# When installing a gem (bootstrap-wysihtml5) do I have to manually move javascript and css files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline, bundler

I think I am missing a vital step:

When installing a `gem` (ie. `bootstrap-wysihtml5`) what steps should I take for it to correctly find and reference the javascript and css files.

I add gem `bootstrap-wysihtml5` to my gemfile, and run bundle install.

I place `//= require bootstrap-wysithtml5` in `application.js` and `*= require bootstrap-wysithtml5` in `application.css`.

I get the following error:

```
 Error compiling CSS asset

 Sprockets::File not found: couldnt find file 'bootstrap-wysihtml5.css'
```

Do I have to manually copy the js and css to the relevant app/assets file, or is there a crucial step I'm missing?

Comment: As per doc, the gem for Rails is `bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails`, not `bootstrap-wysihtml5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! Thanks for your help guys.

By moving the position of the javascript references to this order, it now seems to work.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5/b3
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
```

I have no idea why the order would make such a difference. But it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Billy said, the correct gem is `bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails`. The gem installs the JS/CSS without further effort on your part.

1. Add this to your `Gemfile`:

   ```
   gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
   ```
2. Add this to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

   ```
   //= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
   ```
3. Add this to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`:

   ```
   *= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
   ```

Note that `bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails` requires Bootstrap. If you have not already added Bootstrap to your project, follow [these steps](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails) from the creator of this gem:

1. In `Gemfile`, add the following:

   ```
   gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                                 :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails'
   ```
2. Rename `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`
3. Add the following to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`:

   ```
   @import "twitter/bootstrap";
   ```
4. Add the following to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

   ```
   //= require twitter/bootstrap
   ```

Once the gem & Bootstrap are both installed, initialize wysihtml5.

```
<textarea id="some-textarea" class='wysihtml5' placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
      $(elem).wysihtml5();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Apologies that was a mistake in the original posting. I had specified the rails gem correctly as gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'.

I have bootstrap installed also.

After restarting the rails sever, and adding /b3 to the end of the javascript and css requirements, the text area is now showing. However, none of the buttons or formatting tools are present... Simply a small text area with the associated placeholder text. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share your view code and what kinds of errors you are getting in Developer Tools?